# RuntimeException on validation of JsonReaders - Scala - ReactiveMongo

Tags: json, scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I have a case classe to store my userOption that I insert into my User.
The structure of my user is as such:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("55d54d05ece39a6cf774c3e4"),
"main":{  
  "providerId":"userpass",
  "userId":"test1@email.com",
  "firstName":"test",
  "lastName":"one",
  "fullName":"Test One",
  "email":"test1@email.com",
  "authMethod":{  
     "method":"userPassword"
  },
  "passwordInfo":{  
     "hasher":"bcrypt",
     "password":"aslkdjfasdjh"
    }
},
"userOption":{  
  "hotLeadNotification":{  
     "f":"IMMEDIATE"
  }
 }
   }
```

now, I'd like to add an additional option: favoriteNotification.
I changed my case class adding favoriteNotification:

```
    case class UserOption (
      hotLeadNotification: Frequency = Frequency("IMMEDIATE"),
    favoriteNotification: Frequency = Frequency("IMMEDIATE")
    )
    object UserOption{
  implicit val userOptionFormat = Json.format[UserOption]
implicit object BSONObjectIDFormat extends Format[BSONObjectID] {
    def writes(objectId: BSONObjectID): JsValue = JsString(objectId.toString())
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[BSONObjectID] = json match {
      case JsString(x) => {
        val maybeOID: Try[BSONObjectID] = BSONObjectID.parse(x)
        if(maybeOID.isSuccess) JsSuccess(maybeOID.get) else {
          JsError("Expected BSONObjectID as JsString")
        }
      }
      case _ => JsError("Expected BSONObjectID as JsString")
    }
  }
val userOptionForm = Form(
  mapping(
        "hotLeadNotification" -> text, 
        "favoriteNotification" -> text
   )((hotLeadNotification: String, favoriteNotification: String) =>
   UserOption( 
   hotLeadNotification = Frequency(hotLeadNotification), 
   favoriteNotification = Frequency(favoriteNotification)
   )  
   )((u:UserOption) => Some(u.hotLeadNotification.f, u.favoriteNotification.f))
)  
 implicit object UserOptionBSONReader extends BSONDocumentReader[UserOption] {
    def read(doc: BSONDocument): UserOption = 
      UserOption(
      doc.getAs[Frequency]("hotLeadNotification").getOrElse(Frequency("IMMEDIATE")), 
      doc.getAs[Frequency]("favoriteNotification").getOrElse(Frequency("IMMEDIATE"))
      )

  }
  implicit object UserOptionBSONWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[UserOption]{
    def write(userOption: UserOption): BSONDocument = 
      BSONDocument(
          "hotLeadNotification" -> userOption.hotLeadNotification, 
          "favoriteNotification" -> userOption.favoriteNotification

      )
  }

}
```

Since I added favoriteNotification, I get a RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: (/userOption/favoriteNotification,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:355) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:348) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.StepIteratee$$anonfun$fold$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:670) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.StepIteratee$$anonfun$fold$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:670) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
```

But there's not list in my code. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: When does error appear? Maybe you are fetching object from db that was saved there before, with different schema.

Comment: Hi Lukasz, Error appears at runtime, actually when the user logs in. Indeed, the previous schema didn't contained favoriteNotification.

Comment: So don't you think, that when user wants to log in, his document needs to be fetched from db, and if it was created before your midification, it doesn't have this field you added and so, when it is being parsed it does not find it, what causes your error? Could that be the case?

Comment: Ah you're right! favoriteNotification is not an Option itself, but UserOption is actually n option. Thus is favoritenotification is not present in the schema it will fail
Thank you very much Lukasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that UserOption was an Option, but not it parameters. As I added only the new option is the case class and not in the database, it was throwing this error.
I changed the case class as adding options:

```
   case class UserOption (
          hotLeadNotification: Option[Frequency] = Some(Frequency("IMMEDIATE")),
          favoriteNotification: Option[Frequency] = Some(Frequency("IMMEDIATE"))  
        )
```